# Will Cassandra load balance automatically on heterogenous hardware node capabilities?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am planning to move from MongoDB to Cassandra for large financial time series data. I plan a test cluster of 3 brand new 16GB i7s with 500GB SSDs, but ideally, I would also like to add a pair of older computers I have lying about, but they're about 1/2 the speed of the new ones (i5s with 12GB RAM and spinning disks). Will I have to perform special manual configuration tricks to get Cassandra to load the faster machines with more rows/work? Or is it really as simple as adding boxes to the cluster without worrying too much if their processor and disk speeds are different? I plan a replication factor of 2.

Basically does Cassandra take into account node performance automatically when load balancing and partitioning? I wouldn't want to add older hardware and see it deteriorate the performance of the entire cluster.

The main motivation for my question is that if I purchase a significant number of nodes today with modern hardware, what happens in 24 months when I add much newer/faster hardware? Do the (by then) older machines hold it back disproportionately to their intrinsic speed disadvantage? Do I have to have homogenous node capabilities for effective clustering?

My question applies not only to processor speed, but also to storage system throughput and latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not automatically load balance to adjust for differences in hardware.  So if you use a default configuration, the slower machines will cause a large drag on overall performance.

But if you use vnodes with the murmur3partitioner, then you can in theory compensate for hardware differences by allocating fewer vnodes to the slower hardware.  This has the effect of mapping fewer partitions to those machines so that on average they will be called upon to do less work.

I think to an extent that can work if the hardware is not *too* different in capability, but you have to figure out the right vnode allocation experimentally since the performance can be impacted by so many different factors, such as CPU speed, memory speed, I/O, etc.

I've found it's much easier to work with matched hardware if possible since hardware from just a few years ago performs markedly worse than newer hardware.